# CSS- Bigcartel Logo and Navigation on the same line?

Tags: css, bigcartel

I'm trying to get my navigation on the same line as my logo so it can be on the right of the logo and not under it. Here is my big cartel website,

http://kicksfactory.bigcartel.com

**Here is the Header.**

```css
/*============= Begin Header Area========================*/

#header-area {
    border-bottom: 1px solid {{ Border_Color }};
    float: left;
    margin: 20px auto auto;
    padding: 0 0 15px;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}

#top-header {
    float: left;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    min-height: 58px;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}

#header {
margin-bottom: 0px;
position: relative;
margin-top: 0px;
}

#header h1 a {
color:{{ Main_Text_Color }};
    float: left;
    font-size: 70px;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 100%;
}

#header h1 {
    float: left;
    font-size: 70px;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    line-height: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 0 !important;
    margin-top: 0;
    max-width: 70%;
    text-align: left;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    width: auto;
}

#header h1 img {
    float: left;
    max-height: 400px;
    max-width: 500px !important;
    min-height: 52px;
}

#header h1 span {
    float: left;
    margin-top: -10px;
    padding: 0;
}

#header.image h1 span{display:none}

#right-header {
position: absolute;
right: 0;
top: 35px;
width: auto;
}
```

**Here is the navigation.**

```css
/* Header Navigation Styles-------------------------------------------------*/


#header-navigation {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    border-bottom: medium none;
    border-top: medium none;
    clear: both;
    display: table;
    margin-top: 0;
    position: relative;
    width: 100.35%;
    z-index: 99999;
    padding-left: 300px;
    text-align: right;
    float: right;
}

#header-navigation ul {
background-color: {{ Header_Color }};
height: auto;
list-style-type: none;
margin: auto;
display: table-row;
padding: 0;
width: 100%;
}

#header-navigation ul > li {
    border-right: 0 none;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 !important;
    min-width: 0;
    padding: 0 40px 0 0 !important;
    position: relative;
    text-align: left;
}

#header-navigation ul li.break {
height: 1px;
padding: 0;
margin-left:100%;  /* use e.g. 1000px if your ul has no width */
}

#header-navigation li > a {
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color: {{ Header_Navigation_Link_Color }};
    display: inline-table;
    float: left;
    font-family: {{ Header_Navigation_Link_Font }};
    font-size: {{ Header_Navigation_Link_Size }}px;
    font-weight: 500;
    height: auto;
    min-width: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 100%;
    word-spacing: 5px;
}

#header-navigation li:hover a {
    color: {{ Header_Navigation_Link_Hover_Color  }};
}

#sub-navigation {
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-top: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}

#categories {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    line-height: 100%;
    margin-left: 0;
    position: relative;
}

.categories-list > li {
    color: {{ Header_Navigation_Link_Color }}; 
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    font-size: 11px;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 100%;
    list-style: none outside none;
    margin-right: 30px;
    padding-left: 0;
    position: relative;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.categories-list a {
    color: {{ Header_Navigation_Link_Color }} !important;
    font-weight: normal;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.categories-list span {
    display: list-item;
    font-size: 11px;
    list-style: none outside none;
}

.categories-list span:hover {
    color: {{ Header_Navigation_Link_Hover_Color  }};
}

.categories-list .sub-categories span {
list-style:none;
}

.sub-categories {
left:-9999px;
position: absolute;
width: auto;
}

.categories-list li:hover ul.sub-categories {
left: 0;
}

#sub-categories {
z-index: 99999;
top:0%;
margin-top: 100%;
list-style: none;
position: absolute;
left: -9999px;
width: auto;
min-width: 100%;
}

#subcat-container {
    background: {{ Background_Color }};
    border: medium none;
    float: left;
    margin-left: -47%;
    margin-top: 0;
    min-width: 100%;
    padding: 10px;
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    width: auto;
    z-index: 999999;
}

.sub-categories li {
float: none;
padding: 0px !important;
}


.sub-categories li a {
    color: {{ Header_Navigation_Link_Hover_Color  }};
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    float: left;
    font-size: 10px;
    font-weight: normal !important;
    list-style: none outside none;
    margin: 0 0 8px;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
    white-space: nowrap;
    width: 100%;
}

.sub-categories li span a:hover {
color: {{ Header_Navigation_Link_Hover_Color  }} !important;
}

.sub-categories li:last-child a {
margin:0px;
}


#header-navigation > ul li:hover ul{ /* Display the dropdown on hover */
    left:0; /* Bring back on-screen when needed */
}

#sub-categories {
left:-999999px !important;
}


/*============= End Navigation Styles========================*/
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  You'll need to include your relevant HTML to make that code snippet useful.  Be sure to narrow the code down to just what is needed to illustrate the problem.

Comment: I'm new to this sorry, but can't you get the html from my site?

Comment: The best part about stackOverflow is that when your question is answered it will be preserved here to help other people with similar problems.  Having your code on your website (which will change when you have the right answer) isn't helpful for future people.  Also, you want to make it easy for people to answer your question.  They are doing you a favor.  So, give them the data they need to help you as conveniently for them as possible.

Comment: I see what you mean, okay let me try to fix it, I'm new to this site :P

Answer (score 0):

Adding these new style rules should work, it specifies a fixed height for the header, and gives the navigation line an absolute position at the bottom of that space to line up with the logo.

```
#header { 
  height: 146px;
}

#header-navigation { 
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove CSS property

```
#header-navigation {clear: both;  padding-left: 300px;width: 100.35%;}
#top-header{width: 100%;float: left;}
```